# Bootstrap implementation with PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

This might seem like a stupid question, I recently purchased a bootstrap theme for implementation into our PHP website. I was under the impression that it was PHP code that we would add our own code to and make it work but I see the files are just html with java and css left and right.

So my question is first, are all themes for bootstrap just pure html code and second WHAT WOULD BE BEST WEBSITE TO outsource a freelancer to do the work for us?

Thank you.

Comment: Templates are sold in various ways, but this template it sounds - is a pure HTML Template. You'll need segment it into templates with whatever PHP  Implementation/Framework you choose to work with.

Answer (score 0):

i use default template bootstrap twitter for my php and my framework php.

my recommendation separate header, menu and footer in a special file.

the main file code only basis.